Non-ASCII Characters Converted to Question Marks in AWS Cloud/Java XML transformation
I am working in an Amazon Web Services cloud environment involving java services that transform XML documents. In some cases, as this transformation occurs, non-ASCII characters are converted to question marks.
To be more specific, it is where we are using scripts provided by the "Oxygen XML" vendor in combination with custom code to compare XML files that it occurs. We have engaged Oxygen Support, but, they have not been able to recreate the issue in their environment. I am also not able to recreate the issue in my local environment when I run the document comparison code - it is only occurring in the cloud environment.
There are other java services in our environment that perform XML transformation and they do not show the problem.
I see that the developer of our custom code treated the file content as strings using the StringBuilder object - would it be advisable to use a java XML tool like JAXB or DOM?  I have tried enforcing UTF-8 encoding via configurations in the java service and in the pod within the cloud without success.
Can anyone offer insight as to how we might be able to overcome this defect?  Please let me know if I can provide more clarity or answer any questions.

Somewhere the content is being processed incorrectly. You can pretty much guarantee that it's not oXygen. You haven't provided enough details to be able to guess or suggest what might be wrong.

As @MadsHansen suggests, this kind of problem is hard to debug, and it's impossible to debug from the information supplied. You need to methodically track the dataflow, step by step: at some point there's a data stream being written in one encoding, and read in a different encoding.

There's nothing wrong with StringBuilder as such; though it may have been used incorrectly. We would need much more detail to help debug this. Often with character-encoding mismatches the reading software misinterprets certain characters as various other characters. Sometimes, though, the software can at least recognise that a character code is incorrect, and in such cases will often replace it with the "replacement character" U+FFFD '�' (NB not '?') https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character Is that what you see? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

I witness similar problem and it's not always easy to solve. But it's possible and Java can help you as it have good XML support.
In Java you distinguish between Readers and Streams. In simplification Readers operate on internal String operations. We can assume they are usually correct.
Then we have Streams. They are usually byte-oriented. From Stream, you can create Reader, but you must provide character encoding. And here is the start of problems.
I seen many XML documents which didn't reflect XML standard and even specifying for example ISO-8859-1 had characters in UTF-8 or ISO-8859-14(Hello UK Government).
The only solution was to try to guess encoding. In my case, I used JAXB and you can pass to Unmarshaller Java Reader. Looking on standard SAX API, it expect only InputStream.
But you can solve even this. Create your own input stream which expect existing input stream. Read first xxx bytes and replace existing XML headers with custom one with correct encoding.
XML Document with UTF-8 chars and wrong header :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

Replace for example with
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Than you don't need to change too much code and you don't need to load all document content to the memory. Unfortunately you will need to do all this on byte level. No nice String API.
Another reason can be default charset of the platform you are running you code. For example most Linux distribution use today UTF-8. If documents are produce in CP-1252, it will not work unless they specify proper encoding.
On windows I think it's even more complicated, but if your tool is running on Java, you should be able to change these parameters with -Dfile.encoding=CP-1252.
Radek
